# Control-d line editing in the lein repl?

Tags: ubuntu, clojure, readline, leiningen

I'm using the lein repl on Ubuntu 12.04. The standard emacs command line editing keys all work as expected (i.e. C-a, C-e, C-f) except for C-d. The Delete key works but deletes the character to the left of the cursor.

What do I need to do get to get C-d to delete the character under the cursor?

Also, I'd like to use C-r to invoke incremental history search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to Leiningen 2.x then you can use the rewritten repl that is all in-process and has access to proper completion. If you're still having trouble, try moving ~/.inputrc out of the way.